# C# HTTP request Max connections

Tags: c#, windows, http, connection

We have a number of webservers(15) and for each server have a number of URLs(30).
I have written a Windows Desktop app that goes out and hits each server and each url combo. (using the httpWebRequest.Proxy to do this).
It's usually just for 2 servers at a time. So a total of 60 requests.

The first problem was the 2 connection limit, so I added this to the Form Load:
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500

That helped, but then I seem to run into another limit.

After we roll code out for these sites, they can take a while to respond. The init process takes like 30-40 seconds! That's another story though.

But there seems to be a Windows XP connection limit. If I have IE open and am trying to access a site, while I a running my app to check sites, the IE takes a long time until it gets a page back. Once the app starts getting requests back and closes them, then IE gets it's response back as well.

Also the page we are calling gives us back timings of how long it took to call other WebService calls. These times are sometimes slow, but sometimes quite fast.
I have a timer on each HTTP Request I make that starts the timer once I make the request. Sometime the difference between the page's specified response time and the HTTP request's timer is quite large, like 40 seconds.

So what I think is happening is the request is being queued up and it's timer is running, but has not yet been sent to the page.

Does anyone know what I would need to change to increase the total connection limit in Windows XP? I have read about registry changes or tcpip.sys editing, but would like a definitive answer from the wise and intelligent group at Stackoverflow.

Thanks and I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Just to let you know. I did try changing the tcpip.sys and that didn't work. I changed to 100 and still a delay

Comment: Are you seeing an event log error message referencing event ID 4226? If not, then your change to tcpip.sys worked, but if you are, then you may want to double-check. See http://serverfault.com/questions/51597/how-to-fix-tcp-ip-has-reached-the-security-limit-event-message for further discussion.

From your description, however, I wonder if the larger issues isn't on the server side. If I've read your description correctly, you are issuing 30 simultaneous requests per server. Can the servers accept that many at one time?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try addding this to your app.config:

```
<configuration> 
  <system.net> 
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="65535" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net> 
</configuration>
```